# BLAST server download

Tags: sequence-alignment, blast, webservice

I discovered that Phytozome's BLAST results look quite nice (please see below). 
By any chance, does anyone know where to download this BLAST server in order to install it locally for organisms which are not part of Phytozome?

[image]

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the BLAST server you're referring to unfortunately.

But another BLAST server, SequenceServer looks quite nice too. And has a bunch of helpful visualisations that you can download directly in png or svg. Source code and installation instructions for this one are at http://sequenceserver.com

My opinion is biased because [my lab](https://wurmlab.com) makes SequenceServer. But there is also social proof: dozens and dozens of community websites use it, and it get [cited regularly](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=1988041843760551302,5980610465470832900,4588167011929671798,10707512076571248813).

Apologies for spamming a bunch of screenshots. I think they're helpful to understand what SequenceServer can do & I'm proud of what we've built.

(it's open source so you can install it on your own server, or use our [cloud BLAST hosting service](https://sequenceserver.com/cloud)).

### Overview of how hits align to query

[image: Aligning segments]

### Lengths of queries and hits

[image: Lengths of queries and hits]

### Kablammo pairwise comparison of hit-query alignment

[image: Kablammo pairwise comparison of hit-query alignment]

### Circos overview of BLAST results

[image: Circos/circoletto overview]

### Search interface (automatically detects query type & chooses BLAST algorithm)

[image: BLAST search submission interface]

### Example BLAST result overview

[image: BLAST result]